# Qemu using too much disk

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, libvirt

I am using Centos 7 on the host, and with QEMU emulation windows server, I create a 15 GB disk, then after a week or so, the disk goes to 30 GB, is there a way to stop this? I am using snapshots. Is there any windows service that may be creating lots of files, or maybe the HD is being used as RAM to imprive system? from 15 GB to 30 is a lot, and the server's HD is not bigger, so It's a big issue to me. I reinstalled all and turned a lot of things off, but the same thing happens again. Little help here.

Comment: My guess is swap (pagefile) but this isn't a programming question, so you'd be better off asking on SuperUser or so. (http://superuser.com/ )

Comment: Hey man, thanks. I am sorry it's in the wrong place. Ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention what kind of disk image you're using, and what its configuration is. I'm guessing from your description that its a qcow2 image, since you mention use of snapshots. Snapshots stored inside the qcow2 image will increase its size beyond that visible to the guest OS. eg if you create a qcow2 image that has a virtual disk size of 15 GB, then it is possible for it to consume much more than 15 GB on the host if you have saved multiple different snapshots in the image and the guest has been writing alot of data between each snapshot. Even when snapshots are deleted, this space consumed by qcow2 won't be released back to the OS normally. So while seeing 30 GB of usage sounds quite large it is not totally unreasonable if using snapshots alot.